# Как вывести содержимое того блока, на который нажал?

Tags: wordpress

В общем у меня есть страница с карточками, они создаются через acf repeater, по клику на карточку должна открыться страница на которой должны отобразиться элементы для данной карточки на которую кликнул. Они также созданы через acf. Сейчас выводится содержимое со всех карточек.
Сейчас я переделал и сделал следующим образом.
Есть рубрика с записями, записи выглядят как карточки на которые кликаешь и должно отображаться их содержимое, я пока не придумал как с помощью acf добавлять файлы к конкретной записи. Решил попробовать просто в самом посте добавлять ссылки, но как их отобразить на странице, с помощью какой функции?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.